# Expressjs - Cannot set property 'userId' of undefined in session variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, mean-stack

I am implementing sign in and sign up functionality in express.js using mysql database. My sign up logic is working fine. but login is not working. instead, it throws the error,

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'userId' of undefined
>   and
>   throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>   my routes/user.login code is as follows.

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
var message = '';
var sess = req.session;

if(req.method == "POST"){
   var post  = req.body;
   var name= post.user_name;
   var pass= post.password;

  var sql="SELECT id, first_name, last_name, user_name FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='"+name+"' and password = '"+pass+"'";
  db.query(sql, function(err, results){
     if(results.length){
        req.session.userId = results[0].id;
        req.session.user = results[0];
        console.log(results[0].id);
        res.redirect('/home/dashboard');
     }
     else{
        message = 'Wrong Credentials.';
        res.render('index.ejs',{message: message});
     }

  });
    }else {
        res.render('index.ejs',{message: message});
 }
};
```

and my login.ejs file is as follows.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

 </head>
 <body id="clrblk">
    <div class="container">
    <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-info" >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                    <!--<div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>-->
                </div>

                <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
                                                                    <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
                                                                                <div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"><%= message %></div>
                                                                    <% } %>

                    <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/login">

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" value="" placeholder="username">
                                </div>

                        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                                </div>



                        <div class="input-group">
                                  <!--<div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                      <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                  </div>-->
                                </div>


                            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                <!-- Button -->

                                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                  <button id="btn-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login  </button>


                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                        Don't have an account!
                                    <a href="/signup">
                                        Sign Up Here
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>



                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you do not have session module installed in your application. Install `express-session` using the following `npm`command

```
npm install express-session
```

Then `require` and configure it in your `app.js` file

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'your secret', saveUninitialized: true, resave: false}));
```

After that, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Expression-session wasn't installed. After installing and configuring it in app.js, my app worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the coming readers, if still you can't solve your problem after installing `express-session` module, then read this.

I had the same issue as I am still learning NodesJS, Express ...

My mistake was that I used the `expressSession` middleware somewhere in the bottom of my `index.js`

However, MiddleWares should be defined at the very beginning. That said, I got the error before the parser reached my `expressSession` middleware.